# Remove char columns with little variation

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this

```
Temp=c(26:30)
Feels=c("cold","cold","cold","hot","hot")
Time=c("night","night","night","night","day")
Year=as.character(c(2011,2015,2010,2015,2015))
DF=data.frame(Temp,Feels,Time,Year)
```

I would like to remove all categorical / numeric columns with little variation. eg when the proportion of the most frequent value is >80%, like in "Time" and "Year".
Any ideas with dplyr or other methods?

Comment: The `tidymodels` package implements a version of this: https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_nzv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`'s `select_if` and remove weakly variable columns:

```
Feels <- c("cold", "cold", "cold", "hot", "hot")
Time <- c("night", "night", "night", "night", "day")
Year <- as.character(c(2011, 2015, 2010, 2015, 2015))
df <- data.frame(Temp = rnorm(length(Feels)), Feels, Time, Year)
library(tidyverse)
threshold <- .8
is_variable <- function(x) {
  !(max(table(x) / sum(table(x))) >= threshold)  
}

df %>% select_if(is_variable)
```

Output:

```
> df %>% select_if(is_variable)
        Temp Feels Year
1 -0.6747300  cold 2011
2 -0.4504562  cold 2015
3 -1.4048543  cold 2010
4 -1.7972187   hot 2015
5 -0.6955777   hot 2015
```